# Authenticate Azure Table storage from ADF using Service Principle or Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-table-storage, linked-service

I am trying to load data from Azure Table Storage to ADLS Gen2 parquet files using a copy data activity in ADF.
While creating the linked service for azure table storage, the authentication method shows below 2 options alone.

1. Account Key
2. SAS URI

Is there any other option to connect to azure table storage using service principle or managed identity?

Comment: Currently only these two options are there to connect Azure Table Storage Using ADF activities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure table storage dataset in adf supports only account key and sas uri for now. Alternate option is odata service can be used to connect to azure table storage using service principal.